# Как сделать сбоку инфо и картинку?

Tags: php, html, css

У меня одна проблема: не могу сделать сбоку инфо и картинку. Вот план: 
[image]

Что мне надо сделать, если у меня вот такой код:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/widget_logo.gif">
<div align='center'><table align='center'><tr><td> <img src="/images/В online.png"></td></tr><tr><td>

<form action="Страница" method="post">
                Логин: 
    <br />
    <input name="login" id="login" type="text" />
    <br />
    Пароль:
    <br />
     <input name="password" id="password" type="password" />
    <br />
     <input id="autoin" type="checkbox" />Запомнить
    <br />
    <input type="submit" style="background-color: #6286ab;" value="Войти" />
        </form> 
        </td></tr></table></div>
```

Comment: По конкретнее... И лучше дивами пользуйтесь чем таблицами!

Comment: Если дивами, тогда просто: float:right; в css и всё гуд. Или что ещё нужно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если под html 4.01

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/widget_logo.gif">
<table align='center' width='85%'>
<tr>
<td colspan='2'><img src="/images/В online.png" alt='' /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='250'> 
<form action="login.php" method="post">
             Логин: 
    <br />
    <input name="login" id="login" type="text" />
    <br />
    Пароль:
    <br />
     <input name="password" id="password" type="password" />
    <br />
     <input id="autoin" type="checkbox" />Запомнить
    <br />
    <input type="submit" style="background-color: #6286ab;" value="Войти" />
        </form> 
</td><td>

тут содержимое
</td> 
</tr></table>
```

Кстати, если вы не используете `JavaScript`, то нет смысла использовать идентификатор (`id`) и строчку `<input id="autoin" type="checkbox" />Запомнить.` Если вам нужен этот чекбокс, то дайте ему имя. (аттрибут name)

Comment: опять же ижет не по центру, а практически ссбоку(

Comment: сдесь не правильно написанно не 

<table align='center' width='20%'> 

а 
<table align='center' width='50%'>

Comment: где, вы у меня видите 20%?

Comment: ой извините, 85%

Comment: @Node_pro, не

>индикатор(id)

а 

>идентификатор id
 
или

>аттрибут id

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать